# Python Counter throwing cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects

Tags: python

So I have some python code that is supposed to confirm how many lines (\n) I have in a file before processing. I have this code:

```
doc_contents = context.getFileService().readFile(filePath)
context.logDebug("doc_contents is of type:"+str(type(doc_contents)))
context.logDebug("CSV file read:"+doc_contents)
if Counter(doc_contents)['\n'] < 2 or (Counter(doc_contents)['\n'] == 1 and !doc_contents.endswith('\n')):
```

The doc_contents are read fine.  The type is "unicode"  and the CSV file is printed to the logs just fine.  I can even see the ^m in vi so I know there are the correct new line characters.  But this line keeps throwing cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects message.  I am very new to python but I don't see where I am trying to use a list

Any Ideas?

Comment: Why build a `Counter` at all. `unicode.count` can do the counting.

Comment: Furthermore, you **keep creating a new `Counter` object in each comparison**. Also, don't use the **bitwise not operator:** `!`, use the boolean not, `not`

Comment: There are a bunch of things wrong in your code (such as the fact that the second condition in your `or` expression is a subset of the first), but none should give you the error you describe. Can you give the full traceback and maybe some example data that reproduces the issue for you?